# how can i allow a user to open a file and add each new file of the file into a listBox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm fairly new to c# and visual studio so im sorry if this is a really stupid question.

I tried:

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    listBox1.Items = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

but `listBox1.Items` is read only so I can't.

how can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: _listBox1.Items.Add( openFileDialog1.FileName)_

Comment: You're also displaying the dialog TWICE.  Get rid of the first line and only keep it in the `if` statement.

Comment: consider tagging wpf as a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Add() Method should do the trick:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add?view=netcore-3.1) for more information.